# Prevent bootstrap carousel from sliding when clicking on right side of image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I noticed that when you click on the right hand side or left hand side of a bootstrap carousel image it will slide to the next frame. Is there a way to prevent it from going to the next image unless I click directly on the glyphicon control?

Ex. I only want to slide to the next image if I click directly on the arrow.

In my case I'm using these controls below.

```
<a style="visibility: @visible;" class="left carousel-control" href="#profile-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" style="font-size: 20px;" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a style="visibility: @visible;" class="right carousel-control" href="#profile-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" style="font-size: 20px;" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by adding a higher z-index value: 200

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This is more of a css question than anything. Here's the edited css and html with the addition of the FA trashcan. Sorry for not being clearer earlier.

Here is a jsfiddle that does what you would like it to do as well
https://jsfiddle.net/xgilmore/rdfzngz9/1/

```
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="trash"><a href="#"> <span class="fa fa-trash-o"></span></a></div>

.item {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    z-index: 0;
}

.carousel-control{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 3%;
    height: 3%;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.);
    background-color: none;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
}

.carousel-control.left {
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-image:none;
    z-index: 1;
}

.carousel-control.right {
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-image:none;
    z-index: 1;
}

.trash {
    float: right;
    z-index: 99;
    margin-top:-20px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying, but I interpret it as what I'm currently using, which is what I have posted, will give me the functionality that I want. Which is to only slide to the next image when I click on the arrow but not anywhere else. But this is not the case.

Comment: @user1186050 "carousel-control" adds a lot of css. by removing that class you can more easily target just the chevrons.

Comment: that seems like a lot of work. My purpose behind this is to get a font awesome icon of a trash can to click that I have overlayed on the image. If the icon is all the way on the left or right then the image gets changed when I click the trash can. I don't want that.

Comment: I think maybe setting the z-index will work. I'll post a solution if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by adding `pointer-events: none` to `.carousel-control-prev` and `.carousel-control-next` (so that the click event passes through the element), and adding `pointer-events: initial` to `.carousel-control-prev-icon` and `.carousel-control-next-icon`. This way, a click on the icon still allows sliding to the previous/next slide.

Answer (score -2):

Use data-interval="false"
it will prevent automatic sliding.

Answer (score -2):

$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: false
});